# Is it possible to detect that a user exists or not on my.forms.app using a python?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, request

Hey so i created a code where i can detect whether a website exists or not, this is the code that i use to detect that.

```
exist=[]
url = []

for b in websearch:
    try:
        request = requests.get(b)
        if request.status_code == 200:
            exist.append(b)
            print('Exist')
    except:
        print('Not Exist')
```

but there's another barrier that i have to go through and that is non-existent user from [my.forms.app](https://my.forms.app).

This is one of the example sites.

[image: user not found]

Since on [my.forms.app](https://my.forms.app) you can just create a random name on the link and it's going to redirect to that webpage. is there a way where it can differentiate whether the user exists or not.

Thanks for the help!

**EDIT:**

I tried to make it that if it's 200 it `exists` if it's 204 `user does not exist`. is there a way where it would say `user does not exist if it's 204`

```
try:
    request = requests.get('https://api.forms.app/user/infobyname/minecraft123')
    if request.status_code == 200:
        print('Exist')
    elif request.status_code == 204:
        print('User does not exist')
except:
    print('Not Exist')
```

**2nd EDIT:**
I have found the solution and it's rather simple, i just need to not use try and except in my code.

```
exist2=[]

for c in web:
    request = requests.get(c)
    if request.status_code == 204:
        print('user does not exist')
    elif request.status_code == 200:
        exist2.append(c)
        print ('user exist')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use your browser's network inspector to see what's happening in cases that aren't as clear-cut.

`https://my.forms.app/SOMETHINGRANDOMHERE` makes a request to `https://api.forms.app/user/infobyname/SOMETHINGRANDOMHERE`, which returns a HTTP 204 No Content response if the user doesn't exist.

For a valid username, e.g. `https://api.forms.app/user/infobyname/minecraft` returns 200 and some JSON describing the user.

```
>>> requests.get("https://api.forms.app/user/infobyname/SOMETHINGRANDOMHERE").status_code
204  # not found
>>> requests.get("https://api.forms.app/user/infobyname/minecraft").status_code
200  # found
```

Comment: https://my.forms.app/minecraft this is one of the example an existing site

Comment: let me give that a try

Comment: I tried to request it and it still outputs 200 instead of 404 or 204. Is this the right line to use `requests.get`?

Comment: i have tried and it works, but when i tried to make it if it's == 200 `Exist`, elif it's == 204 `User Does not Exist`. you can see my edit on the new code if i did it correctly or not. @AKX

Comment: The user `minecraft123` exists, so you're getting `exist`. Don't use bare `except:` though, you'll never know if there's a bug in your code or if something happens on the remote end.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249249/discussion-between-tsukuru-and-akx).

Comment: No, sorry, I don't have the time to chat about this.